Typeface of Italian postage stamp from 201x
I've tried several online font identification services, but none has succeeded. Do you know the typeface of this postage stamp? The most significant feature is the dotless "i". The typeface looks modern to me. I don't think the digits in the date necessary is part of the same typeface.


Not an exact match, but it looks similar to FF DIN Pro Light, or likely  some derivative of that, except for the missing tittle on the lower case i.  The numbers don't match however, as this was obviously printed using a franking machine since the numbers are all misaligned.


Thanks, this is a very close match! I'll mark this as solved. May I ask how you did to find this font?

@telephone I'm familiar with the font, so I recognised it.

@telephone note that there are also other varieties of DIN, such as URW DIN, and DIN 2014, both of which are available on the Adobe Fonts site. They all look kind of similar.
